# How to implement trial experience in native C++ application (without XAML)

Tags: c++, native, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, trial

Can I implement trial mode in my native c++ application (cocos2d-x-win8)

All examples shows C#/XAML and I cannot find anything working in c++

Comment: Sure: Use `try { /* main program */ } catch (...) { }`. You can use the catch block to handle users who jump ship.

Comment: Do you mean "try my application for X days" or some such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking about Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8 but luckily the answer is pretty similar. On WP8/Win8 from C++/C# you should use CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsTrial. However, due to a bug in WP8 invoking **CurrentApp::LicenseInformation->IsTrial** on the app's main thread will throw an exception. So you should on a different thread:

```c
ThreadPool::RunAsync( ref new WorkItemHandler( [](IAsyncAction^ operation)
{
auto value = CurrentApp::LicenseInformation->IsTrial;
}));
```

However, do note that the Win8 store offers a built-in time limited trial and WP8 store doesn't offer that by default. In WP8 you should implement your own trial logic.

Comment: Thanks @JustinAngel, but I still got some problems with WP8 trial 

`auto value = CurrentApp::LicenseInformation->IsTrial;`

the above code in my emulator always returns false, is it enough to run above code only or shall I configure my app somehow in order to make it "trial enabled"

Comment: WP8 Emulator doesn't support CurrentAppSimulator like Win8 does. Basically, CurrentApp doesn't have development time support. See wrokarounds @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but is it enough just to use above code in my application when I will release it to the market, or shall I add some more configuration (like metadata, xml, etc.)? to my project before a release? I assume that now it returns 'false' but when released to the market it will return a 'true' when it is in trail mode and 'false' when user bought an app?